# Comparar datos en una vista

Tags: mysql

con una conulta:
Quisiera saber como comparar los datos que me da el **Date_add** con la información de la columna fechaDevolucion, siendo estos tipo **DateTime**.

```sql
    Select distinct cliente, pelicula, date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day) as DebioDevolverse
        From Renta
            Where fechaDevolucion = '-'
            and DebioDevolverse < fechaDevolucion
```

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Como te gustaría compararlas? ¿Te interesa que aparezca la diferencia de días entre ambas fechas? ¿Comparar si una es menor que la otra? Explícanos qué quieres que aparezca o qué consulta te interesa hacer y te ayudaremos.

Comment: @DarkIceDust Quiero comparar, saber que fechas de "DebioDevolverse" son menores a "fechaDevolucion", para que me de el cliente que está fuera del tiempo correspondido (DebioDevolverse).
Gracias

Comment: Vale, y entiendo que fechaDevolucion debería coger los datos del date_add que tienes en la consulta, ¿no?

Comment: nonono, fechaDevolucion ya tiene fechas específicas, ahí de una vez intento comparar con el anterior Date_Add

Answer (score 1):

He investigado sobre la función *date_add()* y lo que hace es devolverte un tipo **DATE**.

Al devolverte un tipo **DATE**, si quisieras compararlo con *fechaDevolucion* (**DATETIME** según el enunciado), tendrías que convertir *fechaDevolucion* a **DATE**, de la siguiente forma:

```
select distinct cliente, pelicula, date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day) as DebioDevolverse
        From Renta
            Where fechaDevolucion LIKE '%-%'
            and DebioDevolverse < DATE(fechaDevolucion)
```

(También añadí la última línea donde sacará la fecha de *fechaDevolucion* y compara que la fecha en *fechaDevolucion* sea menor que *DebioDevolverse*, según he entendido). Puedes hacerle modificaciones hasta que quede justo como lo quieres.

Si necesitas cualquier duda, mejora o aclaración házmelo saber en los comentarios de la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, te he entendido perfectamente.
Se te agradece.

Comment: Genial! Pruébalo si quieres y me comentas :)

Comment: Lo probé, pero me vuelve a aparecer el error 1054, no se encuentra la columna 'DebioDevolverse' en la clausula Where, lo intenté arreglar pero no pude.
Puede ser porque la información DebioDevolverse no está fijo en una tabla?

Comment: acabo de ver y al parecer se evalúa de primero el where y después el select, acabo de poner el **Date_add** en el where, como me puedo referir al **Date_add** en el where?

`
Select distinct cliente, pelicula 
  From Renta  
   Where (date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day)) 
            and fechaDevolucion = '-'
            and DebioDevolverse < Date(fechaDevolucion);`

Comment: Puede ser por eso mismo, prueba con lo siguiente
select distinct cliente, pelicula, date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day) as DebioDevolverse
        From Renta
            Where fechaDevolucion = '-'
            and date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day) < DATE(fechaDevolucion)

Comment: Claro el error es por la asignación que hacemos arriba en el select, cuando decimos que date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day) as DebioDevolverse, ahí tenemos un nombre para la columna que se crea solamente para esa consulta; DebioDevolverse no existe fuera de ahí, por lo que no podríamos comparar un nombre temporal de una columna con una columna en sí. Prueba directamente como te dije en el comentario de arriba y me cuentas!

Comment: estaba probando de la forma que me mandaste y con eso no me regresa absolutamente nada, pero le estoy dando de esta forma y el único problema es que no me da los nombre de los que no devolvieron (Este es el signo "-")


Select distinct cliente, pelicula, fechaDevolucion
  From Renta  
   Where (date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day)) < Date(fechaDevolucion)
            and fechaDevolucion like '%-%';

Comment: ¿El resto de valores te los saca, pero "clientes" no?

Comment: Lo acabo de arreglar, quedaría así 

` Select distinct cliente, pelicula, fechaDevolucion
  From Renta  
   Where (date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day)) < fechaDevolucion or (fechaDevolucion like '%-%');`

Muchas gracias, fuiste de gran ayuda.

Comment: ¡Genial! Si puedes, ponlo en una respuesta para que si alguien tiene la misma duda que tú o similar, la encuentre; me alegro de que lo hayas conseguido, buen trabajo.

Comment: Gracias, ahorita lo pongo.

Answer (score 1):

Quedaría así

```sql
Select distinct cliente, pelicula, fechaDevolucion
        From Renta  
            Where (date_add(fechaSalida, interval diasRenta Day)) < fechaDevolucion or (fechaDevolucion like '%-%');
```

Se evalúa antes el where que el select por eso se puso el **Date_add** en el where para evitar el Error 1054.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).